# Can reserved keywords be aliased in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, alias, keyword, reserved-words

Ruby comes with an `alias` reserved keyword. However it seems that unlike the shell equivalent, you can't use it to alias reserved keyword, like `if`.

Is there any mechanism to do perform such an alias of reserved keywords?

Comment: Sure you can. Fork Ruby, modify this 11000 line [`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) file and recompile. The desired line is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L2958).

Comment: @Eric, I assume you've  tested that.

Comment: Well, that's not a cross implementation solution. The question scope in the language native mechanism. So a more relevant answer to this scope, however not convenient, would be "put your code in a string a parse it".

Comment: Indeed : `eval("puts 3 my_if true".gsub(/\bmy_if\b/, 'if'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The `alias` keyword is for aliasing methods, not keywords.

Comment: I will check this answer if it assert rightly that no such mechanism exists in Ruby, rather than `alias` can't be used to do it.

Comment: You can think of `alias` in bash a sort of *lexical macro* (macro that is based on text replacement), which ruby doesn't have. However, you can easily implement *syntactic macros* by just using methods.

Comment: Could you give an functional example of such a syntactic macro, for example with an "if-else-end" statement with each keyword replaced?

Comment: [Rexical](https://github.com/tenderlove/rexical) seems a candidate regarding *lexical macro* features.